# Android, Can't get weather from google api

Tags: android, weather-api

The following code work well before:

```
class RetreiveWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Bundle, Void, WeatherData> {

        private static final String TAG = "WeatherManager";

        @Override
        protected WeatherData doInBackground(Bundle... params) {
            Utils.log(TAG, "start get weather");
            WeatherData weatherData = new WeatherData();
            Bundle b = new Bundle(params[0]);
            double latitude = b.getDouble(REF_LAT);
            double longtitude = b.getDouble(REF_LONG);

            try
            {
                StringBuilder weatherBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                //weatherBuilder.append("http://www.google.com/ig/api?hl=zh-cn&weather=,,,");
                weatherBuilder.append("http://www.google.com/ig/api?hl=en-us&weather=,,,");
                int la = (int) latitude * 1000000;
                int lo = (int) longtitude * 1000000;
                weatherBuilder.append(la);
                weatherBuilder.append(",");
                weatherBuilder.append(lo);
                String weather = weatherBuilder.toString();
                HttpGet hg = new HttpGet(weather);
                // HttpGet hg = new
                // HttpGet("http://www.google.com/ig/api?hl=zh-cn&weather=,,,39130000,117200000");
                HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse hr = hc.execute(hg);
                String responseString = "";
                if (hr.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                {
                    Utils.logi("", "Location != HttpStatus.SC_OK");
                    return null;
                }
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(hr.getEntity());
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseString.getBytes());

                // URL url = new
                // URL("http://www.google.com/ig/api?hl=zh-cn&weather=,,,39130000,117200000");
                // InputStream is =url.openStream();
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = db.parse(is);

                NodeList currList = (NodeList) document.getElementsByTagName("current_conditions");
                NodeList currList2 = currList.item(0).getChildNodes();

                weatherData.weather = new String(currList2.item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue());

                weatherData.curTemperature = new String(currList2.item(2).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue() + "℃");

                weatherData.wind = new String(currList2.item(5).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue());

                Utils.log(TAG, "Get weather = " + weatherData.weather);
                if (isNeedIconFromNet)
                {
                    weatherData.iconUrl = new String(currList2.item(4).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue());


                    String url = "http://www.google.com" + weatherData.iconUrl;
                    weatherData.icon = getBitmapByUrl(url);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Utils.logi("", "Location get temp Exception e");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return weatherData;
        }
```

But now It return the String: Unsupported API .

Please help me. Is google api closed?
PS. I'm in China.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems like Google has stopped the undocumented weather api service.

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=delhi
Line Number 1, Column 1:Unsupported API
^
```

You may want to try `yahoo weather` or `http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api`.
However, google provided around 4 days weather forecast while yahoo just provides around 2 days forecast (there may be some other way to get more days' forecast from yahoo indirectly).

Answer (score 1):

I think the end of the google weather api has come and google has stopped the service. After all, it wasn't even an officially supported api any way.

iGoogle doesn't seem to use the api anymore either. 
Your best option will probably be to look for a different free weather api.

I'm sure we'll hear more of this change in the next few days.